# C# Strongly Typed Attribute member to describe property

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I was wondering if it was possible to declare An Attribute property that describes a Property so strong typing is required and ideally that intellisense could used to select the property. Class Types works nicely by declaring the member as Type **Type** 
But how to get property as a parameter so that "PropName" is not quoted and is strongly typed?

So far:  The Attibute Class and sample usage looks like

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
 public class MyMeta : Attribute{
   public Type SomeType { get; set; }  // works they Way I like.
   // but now some declaration for a property that triggers strong typing 
   // and ideally intellisense support, 
   public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }    //almost, no intellisence type.Prop "PropName" is required
   public ? SomeProp {get;set;}  //   <<<<<<< any ideas of nice type to define a property
 }

public class Example{
  [MyMeta(SomeType = typeof(SomeOtherClass))]   //is strongly typed and get intellisense support...
  public string SomeClassProp { get; set; }
  [MyMeta(SomeProp = Class.Member)]   // <<< would be nice....any ideas ?
  public string ClassProp2 { get; set; }
  // instead of
  [MyMeta(SomeProp = typeof(T).GetProperty("name" )]   // ... not so nice
  public string ClassProp3 { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:**
To avoid using property name strings i built a simple tool to keep compile time checks whilst storing and using property names in places as strings.

The idea is that you quickly refer to a property via its type and name with intellisense help and code completion from like resharper. Yet pass in a STRING to a tool.

```
I use a resharper template with this code shell

string propname =  Utilites.PropNameAsExpr( (SomeType p) => p.SomeProperty )
```

which refers to

```
public class Utilities{
  public static string PropNameAsExpr<TPoco, TProp>(Expression<Func<TPoco, TProp>> prop)
    {
        //var tname = typeof(TPoco);
        var body = prop.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression;
        return body == null ? null : body.Member.Name;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can use `typeof` for Type name, but have to use a string for the member name. This is as far as you can get:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
 public class MyMeta : Attribute{
   public Type SomeType { get; set; }
   public string PropertyName {get;set;}
   public PropertyInfo Property { get { return /* get the PropertyInfo with reflection */; } } 
 }

public class Example{
  [MyMeta(SomeType = typeof(SomeOtherClass))]   //is strongly typed and get intellisense support...
  public string SomeClassProp { get; set; }
  [MyMeta(SomeType = typeof(SomeOtherClass), PropertyName = "SomeOtherProperty")]
  public string ClassProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, Not the answer I was hoping to see. No strong typing on members as parameters :-(

Comment: I'll mark as answer, until someone proves you wrong ;-) in another 7 mins