# Q&A - How to get the name of Property / Function / Action / Method (of an Interface or Class), in a strongly type way?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, proxy, strong-typing

**Problem description**

Assuming you have an interface / class, and wish to get a Property/Func/Action name, how and what is the best practice to do so?

e.g. given:

```
public interface IConvertible
{    
    // ...
    bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider);
    // ...
}
```

How to get the name of 'ToBoolean' method, in a strongly-typed way?

Also, how to **get the property name** of IsValueCreated from

```
Lazy<object>.IsValueCreated
```

**Motivation**

When you'll do reflection on an interface [method / property / etc], the compiler will help you find all references to it.

Comment: Get what name? The methods name?

Comment: Which C# version are you on?

Comment: Using .Net 4.5v, get 'ToBoolean' name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For .Net 5 and above:** 
use [nameof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) (credits to [m-kazem-akhgary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4767498/m-kazem-akhgary))

**For .Net 4.5v and below:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

using LazyHelper = DotNetSandbox.InterfaceNames<System.Lazy<object>>;

namespace DotNetSandbox
{
    // Use case / Example:
    [TestClass]
    public class InterfaceNamesTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void InterfaceNamesTest()
        {
            // Option 1 - Not strongly typed
            string nameA = typeof(IConvertible).GetMethod("ToBoolean").Name;
            Console.WriteLine(nameA);    // OUTPUT: ToBoolean
            string nameB = typeof(Lazy<object>).GetProperty("IsValueCreated").Name;
            Console.WriteLine(nameB);    // OUTPUT: ToBoolean

            // *** Option 2 ***************
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Option 2 - Strongly typed way:");
            IConvertible @interface = InterfaceNames<IConvertible>.Create();

            Func<IFormatProvider, bool> func = @interface.ToBoolean;
            string name1 = func.Method.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(name1);   // OUTPUT: ToBoolean

            string propName = InterfaceNames<Lazy<object>>.GetPropertyName(i => i.IsValueCreated);
            Console.WriteLine(propName);   // OUTPUT: IsValueCreated
            //OR (For short version - declare alias using, see using region..)
            string propName2 = LazyHelper.GetPropertyName(i => i.IsValueCreated);
            Console.WriteLine(propName2);   // OUTPUT: IsValueCreated


            // Other options results with complex/unclear code.
        }
    }

    // Helper class
    public class InterfaceNames<T> : RealProxy
    {
        private InterfaceNames() : base(typeof(T)) { }

        public static T Create()
        {
            return (T)new InterfaceNames<T>().GetTransparentProxy();
        }

        public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public static string GetName(Delegate d)
        {
            return d.Method.Name;
        }

        public static string GetPropertyName<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> prop)
        {
            // Credits to p-s-w-g
            var body = prop.Body as MemberExpression;
            return body == null ? null : body.Member.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**

- [Using obect's property names in strongly type way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966167/using-obects-property-names-in-strongly-type-way)
- [C# Strongly Typed Attribute member to describe property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872389/c-sharp-strongly-typed-attribute-member-to-describe-property)
- [Get the name(s) of interface methods strong typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412182/get-the-names-of-interface-methods-strong-typed/32245698#32245698)

Waiting for your input / suggestions / insights...

Comment: Respectfully, can you please elaborate why this is not an answer?

Comment: i didnt understand your question first.ok so this is self answered question. another way to get name is keyword nameof. ex: `nameof(ToBoolean)`

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of 'nameof', but it's still new and not supported in .Net 4.5v and below..

Comment: nameof is not a framework feature, it's a C# compiler feature